# clicklistener not working in recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, onclicklistener

Im following this link answer--> https://stackoverflow.com/a/32323801/12553303  ...on click of item im getting an error of invalid product id...but how do i get id from adapter to activity??????? i have used interface for click listener...
need help in here --> `RetrofitClient.instance.deletecart(token, dataList?.get(position)?.product_id.toString())`

on debuuging this line

[image]

following is my code :--

```
class CartAdapter(private val context: Context, private val dataList: MutableList<DataCart?>?) :
RecyclerSwipeAdapter<CartAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() , AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{ //added RecyclerSwipeAdapter and override

var progressDialog: ProgressDialog? = null

private var itemClick: OnItemClick? = null

inner class CustomViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    val mView: View
  val swipelayout:SwipeLayout
    val productiamge: ImageView
    val productname: TextView
    val productcategory: TextView
    val productprice: TextView
    val tvDelete:TextView
    val spin:Spinner
    init {
        mView = itemView
    productiamge= mView.findViewById(R.id.imagecart)
       productname= mView.findViewById(R.id.imagenamecart)
        productcategory= mView.findViewById(R.id.imagecategory)

     productprice =mView.findViewById(R.id.price)
        swipelayout=mView.findViewById(R.id.swipe)
        tvDelete=mView.findViewById(R.id.tvDelete)
         spin = mView.findViewById(R.id.spinner) as Spinner
        tvDelete.setClickable(true);
        tvDelete.setOnClickListener {
            if (itemClick != null) {
                itemClick!!.onItemClicked(getPosition());
            }
        }


    }


}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.addtocart_item, parent, false)

    return CustomViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getSwipeLayoutResourceId(position: Int): Int {
    return R.id.swipe;

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
  val  progressDialog :ProgressDialog= ProgressDialog(context);
    holder.productname.text = dataList?.get(position)?.product?.name ?: null
    holder.productcategory.text = "(" +dataList?.get(position)?.product?.product_category +")"

    holder.productprice.text = dataList?.get(position)?.product?.cost.toString()

    Glide.with(context).load(dataList?.get(position)?.product?.product_images)
        .into(holder.productiamge)

    holder.swipelayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut)
    Log.e("checkidd", dataList?.get(position)?.product?.id.toString())
    // Drag From Right

    // Drag From Right
    holder.swipelayout.addDrag(
        SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right,
        holder.swipelayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper)
    )



    //im not able to get this id in activity
     val id =dataList?.get(position)?.product?.id

    holder.swipelayout.addSwipeListener(object : SwipeListener {
        override fun onClose(layout: SwipeLayout) {
            //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.
        }

        override fun onUpdate(layout: SwipeLayout, leftOffset: Int, topOffset: Int) {
            //you are swiping.
        }

        override fun onStartOpen(layout: SwipeLayout) {}
        override fun onOpen(layout: SwipeLayout) {
        }

        override fun onStartClose(layout: SwipeLayout) {}
        override fun onHandRelease(
            layout: SwipeLayout,
            xvel: Float,
            yvel: Float
        ) {
        }
    })


    holder.swipelayout.getSurfaceView()
        .setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        })


    holder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
        mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(holder.swipelayout)
        notifyItemChanged(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        dataList?.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, dataList?.size!!)
        mItemManger.closeAllItems()
                itemClick?.onItemClicked(position)

    })
    mItemManger.bindView(holder.itemView, position)


}
    override fun getItemCount() = dataList?.size ?: 0

fun progress()
{
    progressDialog?.dismiss()
    val intent =
        Intent(context.applicationContext, AddToCart::class.java)
    intent.flags =
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
    context.applicationContext.startActivity(intent)
    (context as Activity?)!!.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)



}



override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {

}

fun getItemClick(): OnItemClick? {
    return itemClick
}

fun setItemClick(itemClick: OnItemClick?) {
    this.itemClick = itemClick
}
```

}

activity:----------

```
    class AddToCart:BaseClassActivity(), OnItemClick{
   val dataList: MutableList<DataCart?>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.add_to_cart)
    getWindow().setExitTransition(null)
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(null)
    var mActionBarToolbar = findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbartable);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    // add back arrow to toolbar
  setEnabledTitle()

    mActionBarToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
    })
    placeorder.setOnClickListener {
        val intent:Intent=Intent(applicationContext, AddressActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
      loadCart()
}

  fun loadCart(){

  val model = ViewModelProvider(this)[CartViewModel::class.java]

  model.CartList?.observe(this, object : Observer<CartResponse> {
      override fun onChanged(t: CartResponse?) {

          generateDataList(t?.data?.toMutableList())
          totalamount.setText(t?.total.toString())
      }
  })
  }

fun generateDataList(dataList: MutableList<DataCart?>?) {
    val recyclerView=findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.addtocartrecyleview) as? RecyclerView
    val linear:LinearLayoutManager=
        LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerView?.layoutManager=linear
    val adapter = CartAdapter(this@AddToCart, dataList)
    recyclerView?.adapter=adapter
    recyclerView?.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecorator(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.divider)))
   // recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    adapter.setItemClick(this);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    if (dataList?.isEmpty() ?: true) {
        recyclerView?.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        totalamount.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        fl_footer.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        placeorder.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        emptytext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    } else {
        recyclerView?.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        totalamount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        fl_footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        placeorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        emptytext.setVisibility(View.GONE)


    }
  recyclerView?.addOnScrollListener(object :
      RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
      override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
          super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
          Log.e("RecyclerView", "onScrollStateChanged")
      }

      override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
          super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
      }
  })
}
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
 startActivity(intent)
}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)

            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
 loadCart()
}


override fun onItemClicked(position: Int) {

    val token: String = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext).user.access_token.toString()
    RetrofitClient.instance.deletecart(token, dataList?.get(position)?.product_id.toString())
        .enqueue(object : Callback<DeleteResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DeleteResponse>, t: Throwable) {

                Log.d("res", "" + t)


            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<DeleteResponse>,
                response: Response<DeleteResponse>
            ) {
                var res = response

                if (res.body()?.status == 200) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        res.body()?.message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()



                } else {
                    try {
                        val jObjError =
                            JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            jObjError.getString("message") + jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        Log.e("errorrr", e.message)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
}
```

}

need help thanks

Comment: I'm not clear on your question

Comment: can you see this statement in adapter `val id =dataList?.get(position)?.product?.id` ?

Comment: how do i get it in activity?

Comment: Do you know how to implement interface pattern or callback pattern?

Comment: this is my first time ...@JeelVankhede im still trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get response/data back from adapter to activity, you'll need to implement callback pattern like below example:

RecyclerView Adapter sudo code:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(
    other variables,
    private val dataCallback: (Desired data type you want to return to activity) -> Unit // This is how you can construct lambda callback in Kotlin
): RecyclerView.Adaper..(){
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(...) {
        // Let's say here you have click listener or some other event on which you want data to send back to activity then simply call like below:
        dataCallback(outputData) // This can be `dataList?.get(position)?.product?.id`
    }
}
```

Activity callback sudo code:

```
class SampleActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var adapter: RecyclerViewAdapter

    override fun onCreate(...){
        adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(other values) { desiredData ->
            // Here you can receive data back as callback
        }

        // Example from O.P.
        // val adapter = CartAdapter(this@AddToCart, dataList) { output ->  }
    }
}
```

Basically you create a callback receiver type on your adapter constructor as following:

`nameOfCallbackVariable: (TypeOfDataYouWantToProvideBack) -> ReturnType`

I.e. `productSelectedCallback: (Int) -> Unit` where you send your selected id (`Int`) back to consumer.

When you need to provide that data back, you can invoke it like this: `nameOfCallbackVariable(valueOfIntType)`.

Comment: hey need help in spinner --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537639/spinner-value-using-retrofit-and-viewmodel

Comment: It seems to me that you provide lot more details than needed like providing entire code. You should consider limiting scope to actual problem and explain it in details. because I tried to look into and not able to figure out the actual issue in code.

Comment: see from with viewmodel implementation

Comment: i have got an proper solution from without using viewmodel but when i used viewmodel im not able to get an proper output

Comment: thats why i put both methods so that you can understand whats been going on

Comment: hey @jeel can u help me over here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77625974/android-recyclerview-scrolling-with-collapsing-toolbar-issue